# My wifi network card does not support seeing packets not addressed to me. Could I change this by disassmbly of the network driver?

Tags: networking, x86, driver, wireshark, disassembly

I'm learning networking as part of the cisco net academy and we use this tool called Wireshark. It is well documented that most wireless network cards dont support capturing in "promiscous mode" or packets not addresed to their host adress. This is an aribitrary limitaiton, because they see all of them.

BUT I'm pretty good at x86 assembler and disassembly. So I'm currenly looking at the dissasmbly of my network driver. I could just find the place where they are denying it and patch it. **Is the limitation expressed above implemented in the driver or is it part of firmware that I can not change?**

I couldnt find any examples or similar questions sadlly.

Thanks, I think this is more programming than network administration

Edit: Sure! more details:
Dell Wireless 1701 802.11b/g/n and 
Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller

Comment: Since you're asking a very specific question about how a particular feature is implemented, don't you think it would be wise to include an exact description of *what hardware you're talking about*?

Answer (score 1):

> Wireshark. It is well documented that most wireless network cards dont support capturing in "promiscous mode" or packets not addresed to their host adress.

Actually, for Wi-Fi adapters, the key is [monitor mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monitor_mode), not [promiscuous mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Promiscuous_mode).  Most Wi-Fi adapters support monitor mode, but whether the operating system you're using supports it is another matter.

On Linux, *BSD, and OS X, the OS supports it and the driver for an adapter probably supports it if the adapter supports it.

On Windows, however, the first OS to support it is Windows Vista.  Unfortunately, WinPcap, which is what Wireshark uses to capture traffic, doesn't support it even on Windows Vista, 7, 8, or 8.1, so you can't capture in monitor mode with Wireshark on Windows.  Even if it did, the driver for your adapter might not support it, or the support might be buggy.  Making it work would not be a simple job.

Comment: Is there any way to verify that WinPcap has failed to set a specific interface in Windows to "Monitor" mode? and can you link to any officially documentation that WinPcap does not support Monitor mode in Windows for wifi devices, please.

Comment: "Is there any way to verify that WinPcap has failed to set a specific interface in Windows to "Monitor" mode?"  Download the WinPcap source, note the absence of any calls that turn monitor mode on (["Native 802.11 Wireless LAN"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/ff560690.aspx) calls in NDIS to [enable monitor mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/ff568369.aspx)), and conclude that WinPcap is incapable of setting *any* interfaces to monitor mode.

Comment: "and can you link to any officially documentation that WinPcap does not support Monitor mode in Windows for wifi devices, please"  The source code, as per the above; the FAQ doesn't officially document it, although it should.  (Note also, in the documentation, the lack of the official libpcap call to enable monitor mode, `pcap_set_rfmon()`.)

Comment: Thanks for that Guy, it was not the answer I expected. Looking into it , the winpcap people appear to have moved over the commercial offering by Cace and riverbed.com

Comment: Presumably by "the commercial offering by Cace and riverbed.com" you're referring to Riverbed's AirPcap network adapters (CACE Technologies, founded by some of the WinPcap developers, developed and sold the AirPcap adapter; CACE was purchased by Riverbed).

Answer (score 1):

Acrylic WiFi software supports monitor mode under windows 8.1, 8, 7 and vista and installs a driver compatible with wireshark that enables monitor mode capture under windows.

And it's free

https://www.acrylicwifi.com/en/wlan-software/wlan-scanner-acrylic-wifi-free/

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the claim that most wireless network cards don't support promiscuous mode is simply not true. Ability to capture all packets is dependent only on software, not on the device itself. Promiscuous mode support is a pretty basic requirement nowadays and it's most likely supported by your device SW. You should check the vendor documentation to see whether it's true and how to enable it.

The packets control is almost certainly implemented inside FW for efficiency but in theory it can be in the driver as well.